# How to send multipart/data-form through scalaj-http library?

Tags: scala, multipartform-data

I want to implement the following curl command by [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) library:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8" -F file=@1.csv http://10.100.100.100:8028/compute
```

where 1.csv is a local file.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
val url = "http://10.100.100.100:8028/compute"
scalaj.http.Http(url).
   postMulti(MultiPart("file", "1.csv", "text/text", ""))
  .asString
```

I'm suspect `MultiPart("file", "1.csv", "text/text", "")` is not correct.

The prototype of `MultiPart` is:

```
object MultiPart {
   def apply(name: String, filename: String, mime: String, data: String): MultiPart = {
     apply(name, filename, mime, data.getBytes(HttpConstants.utf8))
   }

   def apply(name: String, filename: String, mime: String, data: Array[Byte]): MultiPart = {
      MultiPart(name, filename, mime, new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length, n => ())
   }
}
```

I know the parameter `filename` should be a local file, but I'm not sure what I should pass to other three parameters.

Comment: Try using `text/csv` as mime type

Answer (score 2):

From the `man` page of cURL for `-F` (emphasis mine):

> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has
>   pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the
>   Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. **This enables
>   uploading of binary files etc**. To force the 'content' part to be a
>   file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content
>   part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The
>   difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in
>   the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get
>   the contents for that text field from a file.

The equivalent of that would require you to programatically read the file, and provide the content as an `Array[Byte]`:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import scalaj.http 

val bytes: Array[Byte] = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))
val url = "http://10.100.100.100:8028/compute"
val result = 
  Http(url)
   .postMulti(MultiPart("file", "1.csv", "text/csv", bytes))
   .asString
```